# Media Player replay button

Tags: android, media-player

I am making an app that involves sound. There is a replay button. All I want is, whenever that is hit, my song whenever finished or in play, to be played from the beginning. I have tried many thing like

```
mp.stop();
mp.start();
```

or

```
mp.stop();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

but none of them worked. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to seek player to `0` before you stop it:

```
mp.seekTo(0);
mp.stop();
mp.start();
```

Comment: I don't have any other solution, place your code here